# Sympy doesn't print equations when using matplotlib in PyCharm

Tags: matplotlib, pycharm, jupyter, sympy

I recently started using Pycharm instead of Jupyter on my laptop to do some light scientific work(mainly because I like how it auto-completes the code). 
this code works fine I Jupyter

```
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = sp.symbols("x")
sp.Integral(x, x)
```

but when I run it in Pycharm, nothing happens and I don't get any output and I don't know why.

Comment: I don't see anything related to `matplotlib` in your code except the import command.

Comment: according to Sympy's docs "If LATEX is not installed, but Matplotlib is installed, it will use the Matplotlib rendering engine." you can read it here [link](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html)

Comment: Try to disable **Settings | Tools | Python Scientific | Show plots in tool window**. This option enables PyCharm's special matplotlib backend and it causes the problem I believe.

Comment: I using the community edition. i don't even have this option